# Android app creates file but can't find it

Tags: java, android

I'm having an issue that is preventing me from releasing my app, so maybe you can help.  I have this code to create and write to a file:

```
@Override
public void onClick (View view){
    final String memoryString = memory.getText().toString();
    File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), filename);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    if (location != null) {
        String s = location.toString() + " " + memoryString;
        Log.d(null, s);
        if(fos != null) {
            Log.d(null, "fos not null");
            fos.write(s.getBytes());
        } else { 
            Log.d(null, "Output Stream is null");
        }

        fos.close();
        Log.d(null, "file created!");
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

my log is saying that it's creating the file.  but when I go to access and read from said file, I get the error here that it doesn't exist:

```
try {
    File memoryFile = new File(filename);

    if(memoryFile.exists()){
        revealMarkers(memoryFile);
        Log.d(null, "revealed");
    } else { 
        Log.d(null, "no file found");
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Log.d(null, "file not found");
}
```

Please help if you are able, I am very much stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this ?

```
try {
        File memoryFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), filename);

        if(memoryFile.exists()){
                revealMarkers(memoryFile);
                Log.d(null, "revealed");
        }else{Log.d(null, "no file found");}
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Log.d(null, "file not found");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge! got me going again :)

Answer (score 0):

How is it that you created a file with this statement

```
File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), filename);
```

And then try to retrieve the file with this

```
File memoryFile = new File(filename);
```

Why can't you use the same statement. How is the second statement supposed to determine the directory containing the file?